# ADO.Net data binding to gridview in Windows form application C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have written the below code to fetch the records from database and assign to SqlCommand object. Now my problem is, the query in the backend actually is giving 2 records but in the front end, data grid is populating with only one record. In command object , why am i not getting both the rows. The evil is that dreader is executing one row data only and not the other row. Where am i wrong? Can we populate more than one record sql data into SQl Command object?

```
string sql = "select * from student_detail where (roll_no = '" + txtRollNumber.Text + "') OR (s_name = '" + txtStudentName.Text + "')";
comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

try
{
    dreader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (dreader.Read())
    {
        txtRollNumber.Text = dreader[0].ToString();
        txtStudentName.Text = dreader[1].ToString();
        txtAge.Text = dreader[2].ToString();
        txtCourse.Text = dreader[3].ToString();

        DataRow rd = this.myTable.NewRow();

        rd[0] = txtRollNumber.Text;

        rd[1] = txtStudentName.Text;

        rd[2] = txtCourse.Text;

        rd[3] = txtAge.Text;

        this.myTable.Rows.Add(rd);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use string concatenation if you don't want sql injection. Instead use sql-parameters.

Comment: You need to do a `while (dreader.Read()...`. to move through the reader.

Comment: Thanks tim. Do u have the answer for my question as well ?

Comment: You are not getting two rows because you are using an `if` instead of a `while(dreader.Read()){...}`. But how do you want to show multiple records on single textboxes? You should bind it to a `DataGridView` or something like that.

Comment: Why don't you just Fill `myTable` with a `SqlDataAdapter` instead of doing all that work of creating data rows?

Comment: @Crowcoder lets suppose i want to fetch the records directly based on what all is present in sql server and not using textboxes, what will be the code for that????

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes tim, you are right. Then what should be the approach to show multiple records into datagridview??

Answer (score 0):

In order to consume all the records returned by the data reader, replace the following

```
if (dreader.Read())
```

with

```
while (dreader.Read())
```